# How to remove shower knob?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, shower, bathroom-fixtures

I can't figure out how to remove this shower knob. I have done knob removal before, but this one is quite perplexing. It seems to have a metal cap that I would think would be taken off to reveal a screw. However, I can't get the metal cap off. I have tried hammering a small screwdriver to get under it, but it doesn't seem to separate at all. There is no screwhole or allen wrench hole in the side or anything like that. Any ideas?

[image: shower knob]

Comment: See if you can turn the metal cap counter clockwise while holding the gold knob.

Comment: @JACK Good idea! Sadly, it won't turn either direction.

Comment: Can you see a brand name?

Comment: @Lekcin I don't see a name

Comment: My guess is that the chrome cap should come off. Hard water may have it stuck. Maybe vinegar soaks, and gently prying 360 degrees around and around its edge. I'm thinking something broader and thinner than a screw driver, like a butter knife - used as a lever, not a punch.  Let us know if you figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the thin cap in front of the gold knob should thread off counter clockwise...this could be very difficult to remove ...use thin rubber gloves for better grip....elastics on the cap too will help … if that fails you can get a strap wrench at plumbing supplies store.

Comment: Another good answer, but again it's a bit tough to understand. A minute adding caps and proper sentences would help future visitors get what you mean. Thanks.

Comment: We tried and tried to twist it off, but were unable to. We called a plumber and he used a big channel locks wrench to turn it and it came off. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

There is a special tool called a "puller" for this which looks like a 3-fingered robot claw on a threaded shaft. You can find it in the plumbing/bathroom section at home depot.